# MSI uninstall doesn't delete some files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield

I'm creating an installer for a solution I'm developping, I'm using visual studio installer and InstallShield(for adding custom actions) for editing the msi. When I try to uninstall the product some of the exe files are not deleted however they have the same properties as the files that are deleted. By the way, Permanent option is set to false for all the coponents. Any help is appreciated

Here is a part of the log file

```
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:128]: Doing action: FileCost
Action 14:17:46: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 14:17:46: FileCost.
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: RemoveFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MoveFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DuplicateFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Shortcut 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Class 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Extension 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: TypeLib 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniFile 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F8:10) [14:17:46:129]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ReserveCost 3: -2147287038 
Action ended 14:17:46: FileCost. Return value 1.

MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:107]: Doing action: CostFinalize
Action 14:17:52: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 14:17:52: CostFinalize.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfNoRbDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _D386B34206DC430BB7C8FC35EE7CD517 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _BB8F0E85E8EB46D3B75E324685843D5B property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _DC0312A155324971A559AC1EDBFB020D property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _50114DEFC61246278E4FBF3E7FE6D8BF property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _3FC9D2DC44CA49E9A27ACB5A1AE062B1 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:108]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _3F75608690DC4D06BB5E127E1BF68E47 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:109]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _9F53607884AD446C9F6CA9D8A00AA91F property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:109]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Condition 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:109]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _9F53607884AD446C9F6CA9D8A00AA91F property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _D386B34206DC430BB7C8FC35EE7CD517 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _3F75608690DC4D06BB5E127E1BF68E47 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _3FC9D2DC44CA49E9A27ACB5A1AE062B1 property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _50114DEFC61246278E4FBF3E7FE6D8BF property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _DC0312A155324971A559AC1EDBFB020D property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying _BB8F0E85E8EB46D3B75E324685843D5B property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out\'.
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Target path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Note: target paths subject to change (via custom actions or browsing)
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: TARGETDIR    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: WindowsFolder    , Object: C:\Windows\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: INSTALLDIR   , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: ProgramMenuFolder    , Object: C:\Users\HediNaily\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: DesktopFolder    , Object: C:\Users\HediNaily\Desktop\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _9F53607884AD446C9F6CA9D8A00AA91F    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _603BE8AC6CBF4B45A8A357ABE3D72FE7    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Res\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _D386B34206DC430BB7C8FC35EE7CD517    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _3F75608690DC4D06BB5E127E1BF68E47    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _3FC9D2DC44CA49E9A27ACB5A1AE062B1    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _50114DEFC61246278E4FBF3E7FE6D8BF    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _4BFE245203E14C3CA0DE6AD466BBE645    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\InProgress\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _DC0312A155324971A559AC1EDBFB020D    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: Dir (target): Key: _BB8F0E85E8EB46D3B75E324685843D5B    , Object: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out\
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:110]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\IAOutlookMonitor.exe' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:111]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {D41F027D-4BDD-A7F1-A210-7FA300376514} since another client exists
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:111]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {14435CD0-B5A7-0BC2-5994-728FF0CB28DD} since another client exists
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:111]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {2D5F4F86-4E18-3DE2-22A6-B0C0C2CD6E41} since another client exists
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:111]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {2D5F4F86-4E18-3DE2-22A6-B0C0C2CD6E41} since another client exists
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:112]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\In\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:112]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Temp\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:112]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Error\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:112]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Completed\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:113]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\Out\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:17:52:113]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\IAOutlook\' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
Action ended 14:17:52: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
        Action 14:18:17: RemoveFiles. Removing files
    MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:18:17:057]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=175000)
    MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:18:17:057]: Executing op: SetTargetFolder(Folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\)
    MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:18:17:057]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=IAOutlookMonitor.exe,,ComponentId={52C4741B-8A8C-03CF-F66A-5A5ABA54A703})
    RemoveFiles: File: IAOutlookMonitor.exe, Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\InterAct ES\Bin\
    MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:18:17:059]: Verifying accessibility of file: IAOutlookMonitor.exe
    MSI (s) (F8:78) [14:18:17:075]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=RemoveFolders,Description=Removing folders,Template=Folder: [1])
    Action 14:18:17: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the uninstall and read through it.  You may have reference counting and/or component rule violations that causes Windows Installer to leave the files out of an abundance of caution.

Comment: I've added a part of the log file I got, It seems that the msi is only looking for one file

Comment: The decisions are made earlier during a process known as costing.  This is where MSI determines the current state, requested state and action state of each feature and component.  What you posted is the result of that.

Comment: Clearing Key File has solved the issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you explain how you "Clear[ed the] Key File"?  
I'm having a similar issue when installing on a 64 bit machine certain files are not installed

Comment: InstallShield components show their files and one of them can have a Key next to it.  This is the key file.  Right click it and select clear.